# ORACLE to MSSQL using SSMS Import Wizard with Query to Update Rows

Tags: sql-server, oracle, import, updating

I have a situation which prevent me of updating rows in a table in MSSQL getting the data from ORACLE. I can INSERT fine from ORACLE to MS SQL using a SELECT statement like:

```
SELECT XRECORDACTIVATIONDATE, XRECORDCUTOFFDATE, XRECORDREVIEWDATE,
XRECORDFILINGDATE, XNOLATESTREVISIONDATE, XNEWREVISIONDATE, XDATERECEIVEDDOC,
XINACTIVEDATE, DCREATEDATE, DINDATE, DRELEASEDATE, DLASTMODIFIEDDATE
FROM STELLENT.V_EXPORT_TO_MSSQL V
```

But when I try to update the rows based on an unique ID using:

```
UPDATE D
SET D.XRECORDACTIVATIONDATE = V.XRECORDACTIVATIONDATE
FROM DBO.DOCUMENT D
INNER JOIN STELLENT."V_EXPORT_TO_MSSQL" V ON D.DID = V.DID
```

I get the following error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
 (System.Data.OracleClient)
```

DBO.DOCUMENT is a MSSQL table.
STELLENT.V_EXPORT_TO_MSSQL is a View in ORACLE

I might be writing wrong the query I will appreciate some help. thank you.

Comment: What kind of ETL tool are you using? SELECT != INSERT. Second you are mixing 2 DBs `FROM DBO.DOCUMENT D
INNER JOIN STELLENT."V_EXPORT_TO_MSSQL"` without any kind of db_link/linked server/openrowset.

Comment: I'm just using the integrated import wizard from SQL Server Management Studio. I connected both DB, but I need to work better on my query, I'm trying to Implement the OpenQuery() Functionality but not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Lukasz is correct - a select statement is a lot different from an insert statement.

The ORA-00933 error means your query is not formed properly. This is because in Oracle, the database expects queries to follow a certain format/standard. Typically, queries within Oracle will have a form of SELECT [columns] FROM [tables] WHERE [conditions]. This can vary - for example if you wanted to select all data from a table, that query might look like "SELECT * FROM [table];" and the WHERE clause can be omitted because you do not need to define a condition for the database to return all rows. While queries can vary in form, in general, they will follow some type of format.

You are receiving this error because your query does not conform to the expected form, and it is because you have an INNER JOIN that directly follows your FROM clause. To fix this, I would recommend creating a query that you use to select the records you want to update, and then using that select statement to form your update statement by replacing the "SELECT" with "UPDATE".

For more on SQL Standards and how to format your queries, I would recommend taking a look at Oracle documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_1001.htm#SQLRF52344